# How to send android push notifications automatically when new row inserted in MySQL?

Tags: php, android, mysql, push-notification

Currently I have 2 android applications that share the same MySQL database. The first app will post data to the database. The second app will display the database data. How do I send a push notification to the second app AUTOMATICALLY and immediately after the first app post data to the database ?

Any idea how to solve this with GCM ?

Comment: Your question answers itself really. This https://gist.github.com/prime31/5675017 ?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far??

Answer (score 0):

after posting data to database , do the following code

```
$apiKey = "your api key";

        $db_username    = 'root';
        $db_password    = 'root';
        $db_name        = 'gcm001';
        $db_host        = 'localhost';
        $mysqli = new mysqli($db_host, $db_username, $db_password,$db_name);


        if($mysqli->connect_errno > 0){
            die('Unable to connect to database [' . $mysqli->connect_error . ']');
        }   

        //get registration id's from database, whom you want to send notification  ... assuming you have stored registration ids of 2nd app in database
        $query = "SELECT * FROM RegisteredDevices where userid = $userid";

        $result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);
        $i=0;
        $data = array();
        while($row   = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
            $data[$i] = $row['reg_id'];
            $i++;
        }

        $registrationIDs = array_values($data);
        //print_r($registrationIDs);

        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';



        $fields = array(
                        'registration_ids'  => array_values( $registrationIDs ),
                        'data'              => array( "message" => "Your notification message here" ),
                        );

        $headers = array( 
                            'Authorization: key=' . $apiKey,
                            'Content-Type: application/json'
                        );


        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();

        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url );   
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
         curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode( $fields ) );

        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);

        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch); 

        echo $result;
```

hope this helps....